# Look for volume D if found and volume size is greater than 1tb run DISKPART /S filename

Tags: batch-file, wmic

As far as I understand I can use:

```
WMIC /node:"%computername%" LOGICALDISK GET Name
```

to get the name and I can use:

```
WMIC /node:"%computername%" LOGICALDISK GET size
```

to get the size.

I am have difficulties to get this working using a batch scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As comparing the 1TB size would get difficult with batch, let wmic do the job

```
WMIC /node:"%computername%" LOGICALDISK where "Name='D:' AND Size>1099511627776" Get  Name|findstr "^D:" && (
    DISKPART /S filename
) || (
    Echo Partition is less than 1TB
)
```

Otherwise you don't tell about the difficulties you have.

Answer (score 3):

```cmd
>nul 2>nul (
    wmic logicaldisk where "caption='d:' and size > 1099511627776" | find "Win32_LogicalDisk" 
) && (
    echo Drive found
)
```

This code just executes the indicated `wmic` query (drive `d:` and size greater than 1TB) and checks the output with `find` command to see if any drive has been found, while hiding the output of any message or error by redirecting standard output stream and error stream to `nul` device.

If the output of the `wmic` command contains `Win32_LogicalDisk`, a matching drive has been found and `find` will clear (set to `0`) the `errorlevel`. If there is not a matching drive `find` will fail and raise the `errorlevel` (set to `1`)

The conditional execution operator `&&` (execute next command if the previous one did not set `errorlevel`) is used to check the `find` sucess/failure and determine if `diskpart` should be executed.

Comment: Quite similar answer with a nice explanation (+1)

Comment: @LotPings, maybe it is the most logical approach: let the tools do as much work as they can without additional/unnecessary code. That leads to very similar solutions.